# React router - pass function to children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I´m developing a react-app using **react-router**, **redux** and **redux-saga** with the following structure:

- **App.js**: Place where all my routes are located

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" exact component={Index}/>
  <Route path="/user" exact component={Userlist}/>
  <Route path="/user/:id" exact component={Userdetail}/>
</Switch>
```

- **Userlist.js**:

Stateful component connected to redux and fetching data from my backend. Data is listed in a table and has a link to Userdetail component. 
In the **Userlist** component all state management has to be done (e. g. update/delete an user)
After clicking on one row in the table the Userdetail component is rendered (I pass the user data via Router-Link state to my component).

```
<Link to={{
            pathname: `/user/${props.user._id}`,
            state: {
                user: user
            }
        }} className="stretched-link"/>
```

Passing the data to my userdetail list is working as it should by using state and access it via props.location in my userdetail component.

- **Userdetail.js**:

In this component all other data of the user is displayed. Also there are two buttons which handle the update and delete part. The reference of these two function should be passed as props from Userlist to Userdetail component.

Now I´m coming to my question: 
How can I pass function references from **Userlist.js** to the corresponding child component (**Userdetail.js**)? 
I know there is a way to pass multiple props to a route using the render method instead of the component, but struggle to implement this according to my app structure. If possible I want to maintain all my routes in App.js or a separate file. 
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Is there a reason why would you like to pass function references? Do they cause side effects?

Comment: How can you pass it if after clicking link Userlist component will be destroyed?

Comment: @Dmitry Component will be destroyed but function can be still alive i think. The worst thing is the function inside invokes `useState()[1] setState func` and you can get nice error

Comment: I want to manage all the state in one component and the other is just a presentational component with the buttons for update and delete. What do you suggest in my case as alternative?